# MySQL IF inside a SWITCH CASE statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to put a couple of if statements inside of a CASE WHERE in a select query to control the order by.  This is a simplified version that is still giving me a syntax error.

```
SELECT stt_stid, st_stid, st_prid, st_first, st_last, YEAR(st_graduation)
  FROM sttlink
  INNER JOIN student ON stt_stid = st_stid
  WHERE stt_prid = 3920103
  GROUP BY stt_stid
  ORDER BY
    CASE 
      WHEN (MONTH(now())>='9')
        THEN    
          if(YEAR(st_graduation) = YEAR(now()), 0, 1),
          st_graduation
      WHEN (MONTH(now())<'9')
        THEN
          if(YEAR(st_graduation) >= YEAR(now()), 1, 0),
          st_graduation
      END;
```

And the error message (Navicat) is:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
      st_graduation
  WHEN (MONTH(now())<'9')
    THEN
    ' at line 13
```

Here's more stuff (thanks for looking so far!).  This is my original working version.  The issue is that I need to have two different order by clauses - one when the month is Sept-Dec, and the other for Jan-August.

```
ORDER BY if(YEAR(st_graduation)>=YEAR(now()), 0, 1),
        if(YEAR(st_graduation)>=YEAR(now()), 10000, datediff(now(),st_graduation)),
        st_graduation
```

The above works nicely if it's Jan-August but I need a slightly different one for months Sept-Dec.

Rahul's answer is very close.  Now I'm down to a 2nd case inside the statement:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE 
  WHEN (MONTH(now()) >= '9')
    THEN    
      CASE WHEN YEAR(st_graduation) = YEAR(now()) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
      CASE WHEN YEAR(st_graduation) = YEAR(now()) THEN 10000 ELSE (datediff(now(),st_graduation)) END
  WHEN (MONTH(now()) < '9')
    THEN
      CASE WHEN YEAR(st_graduation) >= YEAR(now()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
      CASE WHEN YEAR(st_graduation) = YEAR(now()) THEN 10000 ELSE (datediff(now(),st_graduation)) END
  END, st_graduation;
```

Should I create a 2nd separate "main" case/when - same when clauses but with just the 2nd case statements?

Comment: post some data sample and expected result. What are you trying to acheive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to do like below using a `Nested CASE` expression

```
ORDER BY
    CASE 
      WHEN MONTH(now()) >= '9' THEN    
          CASE WHEN YEAR(st_graduation) = YEAR(now()) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

So in your case, the `ORDER BY` clause should look like

```
  ORDER BY
    CASE 
      WHEN (MONTH(now()) >= '9')
        THEN    
          CASE WHEN YEAR(st_graduation) = YEAR(now()) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END          
      WHEN (MONTH(now()) < '9')
        THEN
          CASE WHEN YEAR(st_graduation) >= YEAR(now()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      END, st_graduation;
```

Comment: This is very close!  Thank you!  Can I add a 2nd CASE inside each main THEN?  See revised original question

Comment: @Steve, Yes you can. Give it a try and see.

Comment: Thanks Rahul and AlexGreg for the guidance.  Just need to tweak them to get my results in the order that I want but definitely over the hurdle here.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
SELECT stt_stid, st_stid, st_prid, st_first, st_last, YEAR(st_graduation)
  FROM sttlink
  INNER JOIN student ON stt_stid = st_stid
  WHERE stt_prid = 3920103
  GROUP BY stt_stid
  ORDER BY
    CASE 
      WHEN (MONTH(now())>='9' and YEAR(st_graduation) = YEAR(now()))
        THEN 
          st_graduation
      WHEN (MONTH(now())<'9' and YEAR(st_graduation) >= YEAR(now()))
        THEN
          st_graduation
      END;
```